# How to using app() in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I saw someon use `app()` instead of `Yii::$app`

for example:

```
Yii::$app->user->id
app()->user->id
```

How is this possible? and how to use it .

Comment: show us  where you saw  this code .. please

Answer (score 0):

Yii::app() is Yii 1.1

Yii::$app is Yii 2

Comment: Yes I know but i saw app()->user->id in yii2

Answer (score 0):

Each Yii application system contains a single application object which is created in the entry script and is globally accessible through the expression \Yii::$app. It is a global object and you can use it everywhere

```
$userID = Yii::$app->user->id;
$isGuest = Yii::$app->user->isGuest;
```

[Docs about Yii::$app](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html)

Comment: No, this is not true
Yii::$app convert to app()

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own wrapper function in the global scope of the application for this purpose based on the `\Yii::$app`.

```
if (!function_exists('app')) {
    function app() {
        return \Yii::$app;
    }
}
```

And use it like this `app()->user->id`.

By the way, Laravel uses the similar approach to provide an alias to its [service container instance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-app).